# Retrieving information from a signed document DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to DocuSign, have made the tutorials and read through the DocuSign API documentation. I am developing in Java, and have successfully achieved to send documents for signing from a template to an email address. The document then gets opened, a custom field gets filled out. The document gets signed by the user.

Well now here are two questions that arise for me:

1) Am I right with the assumption that custom fields are to be used for virtually any form field like "Which pets do you have?" that a user is expected to fill out? Almost all the other fields which I can add when creating a template are being filled out automatically by DocuSign.

2) I have added a name and surname field as well as a custom field and the  "sign here" field to the template from which I am sending the document via the API. Once the recipient has has filled out the information and signed the document, I would like to request the information which the user has entered into the custom field. How can I do that? I have found various requests for getting the status of a document or envelope. But never found how I can retrieve the actual user input.

Regards
Josef

Comment: Just posted an answer for you, take a look below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DocuSign if you have common tabs that you use for your recipients in your requests then you can use the `Custom Fields` to create them once then re-use them in your subsequent requests.  However, in general if you want to have editable fields where you will gather info from your recipients then you can use the `Text` field and un-check read-only.  If setting through the API it would look like this:

```
"textTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "NameOfTheTab",
      "value": "12345"
    }
```

You can read more about using these fields through the **Features** section of the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

With regards to your second question of how to retrieve the data that your recipients fill out, remember that tabs are always specific to recipients (as opposed to the documents themselves) so take a look at the [Get Tab Information for Recipient API](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm) call.

Example:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```