# Retrieving information from a signed document entered by the signer using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have added textTabs for a signer in an envelope using the DocuSign API.
I would like to request the information which the user has entered into the textTab. How can I do that?

I found the following hint:
[Retrieving information from a signed document DocuSign API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343417/retrieving-information-from-a-signed-document-docusign-api)

But when looking into the REST API [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list/) it is stated that the API retrieves the original value (originalValue) of the tab when it was sent to the recipient.

That is exactly the behaviour I had discovered. 
Does there exist any other method to retrieve the data entered by the signer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches to get the tab values for an envelope:

1) envelopes/(envelopeID)/recipients?include_tabs=true. This will return all tab values for every recipient on the envelope. It does NOT include the originalValue property of a tab though.

2) envelopes/(envelopeID)/recipients/(recipientID)/tabs. You will need to explicitly hit the tabs endpoint for every recipient. This will display the originalValue property.  Example: ../envelopes/5ad452d5-3004-4b8b-b4d1-ef90f02f2c45/recipients/1/tabs

Comment: Good news. If possible can you mark my response as an answer?